# AWS Glue crawler need to create one table from many files with identical schemas

Tags: amazon-athena, aws-glue

We have a very large number of folders and files in S3, all under one particular folder, and we want to crawl for all the CSV files, and then query them from *one* table in Athena. The CSV files all have the same schema. The problem is that the crawler is generating a table for every file, instead of one table.  Crawler configurations have a checkbox option to "Create a single schema for each S3 path" but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Is what I need possible?  Thanks.

Comment: Another option is to crawl based on a manually created table. Aws Glue crawlers can take a table as a source. That way it will not be changing the schema but rather just updating partitions. You can make use of this in scenarios were your CSV files have column heading or you have updated column heading in your table in the catalog. Instead of selecting s3 as a source you can just choose the table from the data catalog.

Answer (score 2):

Glue crawlers claims to solve many problems, but in fact solves few. If you're slightly outside the scope of what they designed for you're out of luck. There might be a way to configure it to do what you want, but in my experience trying to make Glue crawlers do things that aren't perfectly aligned with it is not worth the effort.

It sounds like you have a good idea of what the schema of your data is. When that is the case Glue crawlers also provide very little value. You probably have a better idea of what the schema should look than Glue will ever be able to figure out.

I suggest that you manually create the table, and write a one off script that lists all the partition locations on S3 that you want to include in the table and generate `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION …` SQL, or Glue API calls to add those partitions to the table.

To keep the table up to date when new partition locations are added, have a look at this answer for guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56439429/1109

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you want is to use just one of the tables created by the crawler as an example, and create a similar table **manually** (in AWS Glue->Tables->Add tables, or in Athena itself, with

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `tablename`(
  `column1` string, 
  `column2` string, ...
```

using existing table as an example, you can see the query used to create that table in Athena when you go to Database -> select your data base from Glue Data Catalog, then click on 3 dots in front of the one "automatically created by crawler table" that you choose as an example, and click on "Generate Create table DDL" option. It will generate a big query for you, modify it as necessary (I believe you need to look at LOCATION and TBLPROPERTIES parts, mostly).

When you run this modified query in Athena, a new table will appear in Glue data catalog. But it will not have any information about your s3 files and partitions, and crawler most likely will not update metastore info for you. So you can in Athena run "**MSCK REPAIR TABLE tablename;**" query (it's not very efficient, but works for me), and it will add missing file information, in the Result tab you will see something like (in case you use partitions on s3, of course):

```
Partitions not in metastore:    tablename:dt=2020-02-03 tablename:dt=2020-02-04 
Repair: Added partition to metastore tablename:dt=2020-02-03
Repair: Added partition to metastore tablename:dt=2020-02-04
```

After that you should be able to run your Athena queries.